# Can't access jupyter notebook instantiated in google cloud vm from external IP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook

I've instantiated a ubuntu vm and started a jupyter notebook session.
When I try to access from the external ip provided in the instance, the connection is not allowed.
I've tried to configure a incoming traffic rule on the firewall, but it didn't solve the problem.
Any sugestions?